# Oracle Auto-Increment Primay Key without a trigger

Tags: oracle, primary-key

There are lots of posts that indicate the accepted way to do an auto-increment primary key (like MySQL's auto_increment property) in Oracle is a trigger.

However, what if I don't want a trigger? I've found a number of approaches to this, and I'm wondering what the merits/demerits are of these approaches.

**1st Option**

I think I know why this approach isn't recommended. This is obvious from a human perspective, but potentially dangerous from a database perspective.

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (PK, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES
(((SELECT MAX(PK) FROM MY_TABLE)+1), :bound_name, :bound_password)
```

**2nd Option**

Assuming MY_TABLE_PK is a sequence we've created beforehand:

```
VARIABLE id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    :id := MY_TABLE_PK.NEXTVAL;
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (PK, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES
    (:id,:bound_name,:bound_value);
END;
```

**3rd Option**

Again assuming MY_TABLE_PK is a sequence we've created beforehand:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (PK, NAME, PASSWORD)
SELECT MY_TABLE_PK.NEXTVAL, 'literal name', 'literal password'
FROM DUAL
```

In my experiments, all of these work in certain contexts, though not 100% of the time.

Comment: In what contexts don't the second and third options work? The second seems overly complicated, and the third doesn't need to select from `dual`; you can use `my_table_pk.nextval` directly in the `values()` clause, sort of combining them both (as Lokesh shows). But they should work. Also, the `_pk` suffix would make me think this was a primary key constraint, which would be confusing (especially if it's being used to populate an actual PK); calling it `my_table_seq` or something would be clearer.

Comment: 4th option is an upgrade to Oracle 12.1c and use of it's new identity column `CREATE TABLE tabname( c1 NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, c2 ......` --->  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/gateways.121/e22508/migr_tools_feat.htm#BABJJEEF

Comment: Option 1 seems to randomly create a row contention lock; sometimes it works, sometimes it hangs the DB and I have to kill the session.

I wasn't able to get option 2 to work in PHP using oci_parse(), oci_bind_by_name(), and oci_execute().

Option 3 isn't ideal b/c it requires re-parsing the query every time and opens the possibility of SQL injection if you don't manually sanitize your literals.

Comment: @vaFyreHeart Option #2 requires Oracle 11g, which introduced getting a sequence value in PL/SQL.  And it has a syntax error - remove the `:` from ID.  But even if you're in 10g, you should still be able to `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(PK, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (MY_TABLE_PK.NEXTVAL, :bound_name, :bound_value);`.

Comment: Option 1 also requires a Coalesce() around the Max() in case the table is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach is always this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (PK, NAME, PASSWORD)values (MY_TABLE_PK.NEXTVAL, 'literal name', 'literal password');
```

Its simplest then why go for complicated ones?

Option2 is not at all needed, other options are fine but always take simplest approach to keep less bugs and easy maintence.

Comment: Ironically, I never tried that syntax. I tried INSERT INTO MY_TABLE values (((SELECT MY_TABLE_PK.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL)+1), ...), which failed. Thanks, that's much simpler. It also permits bound parameters, which fixes the santizing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Normally @Lokesh's answer is best.  If you're using 12c then definitely look into @kordirko's comment about `identity`.

Another option is to use [SYS_GUID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions187.htm#i79194) to automatically generate primary keys.  The primary key will use more space than a number but has the added advantage of being globally unique.

```
create table test1(id raw(16) default sys_guid(), a number);
insert into test1(a) values(1);
select * from test1;

ID                                  A
--------------------------------    -
BFFE63BD3ADE4209AC906CECE750C3AE    1
```